# How to use format() on a moment.js duration?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, duration

Is there any way I can use the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) `format` method on duration objects?  I can't find it anywhere in the docs and it doesn't seen to be an attribute on duration objects.

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
var diff = moment(end).unix() - moment(start).unix();
moment.duration(diff).format('hh:mm:ss')
```

Also, if there are any other libraries which can easily accommodate this sort of functionality, I'd be interested in recommendations.

Thanks!

Comment: moment.utc(duration.asMilliseconds()).format('hh:mm:ss'); - A duration is a vector.  By putting its tail on the origin you can use date formatting to get hh:mm:ss.

Comment: moment.utc(moment.duration(23, 'seconds').asMilliseconds()).format('hh:mm:ss')
=> "12:00:23" doesn't work so well

Comment: Ah, I found the issue, `HH:mm:ss` will give `00:00:23` in my previous example. so just the wrong casing on the Hours part

Comment: For those who want to display duration in a readable way, use: `moment.duration(diff_ms).humanize();`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

We are looking into adding some kind of formatting to durations in moment.js. See https://github.com/timrwood/moment/issues/463

A couple other libraries that might help out are http://countdownjs.org/ and https://github.com/icambron/twix.js

Comment: I'm looking forward to duration formatting too. Taking a look countdownjs now, but twix only seems to do "smart" formatting, not much customization.

Comment: While twix works hard to do smart formatting, it has lots of formatting options, right down to the tokens involved: https://github.com/icambron/twix.js/wiki/Formatting. Disclaimer: I'm the author of twix.

Comment: Countdown.js is excellent, and the author is super-helpful (he just released **2 versions** in the same day due to some suggestions I made)!

Comment: Im down-voting because the github issue linked in this answer is just a never ending stream opinions, wishes and rants that lead no where, the issue is still open after 4 years, nothing userful

Comment: Why can't it be identical to the other .format used elsewhere in the library? This is insanity. 5 years and it's still not done? really?!

Comment: Down voting as well. The best option, IMHO is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25386127/282250

Comment: Gonna just downvote this since its an unfulfilled promise

Comment: thanks for proving that momentjs is officially dead

Answer (score 218):

```
// set up
let start = moment("2018-05-16 12:00:00"); // some random moment in time (in ms)
let end = moment("2018-05-16 12:22:00"); // some random moment after start (in ms)
let diff = end.diff(start);

// execution
let f = moment.utc(diff.asMilliseconds()).format("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
alert(f);
```

[Have a look at the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhdd8/920/)

Comment: Good approach. Although it doesn't work if I want to display days as well: `DDD HH:mm:ss.SSS` (where `DDD` is day of year) displays `1` when I want `0`. Any quick fix for that?

Comment: No easy way. I did this  http://jsfiddle.net/fhdd8/14/ , which is probably what you did, but I don't think moment has anything that does this out of the box

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to display 10 quadrillion milliseconds as mm:ss

Comment: this doesn't work past 24 hours (i.e. if I wanted to display 117 hours). otherwise great solution!

Comment: @Phil you can use "D" or "DD" if you'd like to show days.

Comment: @Vinay -- the difference is if you want a leading 0 on the days. see http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: Thanks for this! I needed some literals too, and this works great:
    `moment.utc(diff).format('d[d] h[h] m[m]')`
to output "1d 8h 27m"

Comment: This answer is explaining how to display a formatted MomentJS MOMENT, not a DURATION, as the question states.

Comment: @RavenHursT Not sure I understand what you're saying... var ms declaration is intended to be a duration (substituting the diff of two moments)

Comment: @DavidGlass I see what you're saying now.  Maybe make that a bit more clear w/ something like `var duration = 54321 - 12345`?

Comment: I had to add ".asMilliseconds()" like @TaeKwanJoe's answer to get this to return anything other than 0

Comment: The original question is about moment.duration() not about usual moment. It's  different classes!

Answer (score 105):

convert duration to ms and then to moment:

```
moment.utc(duration.as('milliseconds')).format('HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: So this does not work if your duration is longer than 24h.. 24h is being reset to 0h

Comment: @S.Robijns a useful observation but just to emphasise for others - this *is* the expected behaviour of `.format('HH:mm:ss')`. [See the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 48):

Use this plugin [Moment Duration Format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format).

Example:

```
moment.duration(123, "minutes").format("h:mm");
```

Comment: That formatting doesn't work properly, the duration side is good but if I specify `hh:mm:mm` and only have 10 seconds it shows `10` instead of `00:00:10` (even with forcelength on)  If its not formatting... then it should be called something else, formats should be standardised.

Comment: @ppumkin i know this is old but if you specify `{ trim: false }` it will stop that behaviour.

Comment: This is what I prefer to use:

 Assume you have  duration, like `const duration = moment.duration(value, 'seconds');` than i can be formatted using: 
`moment.utc(duration.as('milliseconds')).format('HH:mm:ss').toString();`

Comment: @EvgenyBobkin that won't work if your duration is longer than a day long, the library will handle it though

Answer (score 30):

Use this line of code:

```
moment.utc(moment.duration(4500, "seconds").asMilliseconds()).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: If the duration is > of 86400'' (i.e. 24h), this will not work.

Comment: It's the same in excel, it will roll over at 24 hrs.  This is a great workaround if you're aware of the 24 hr limitation.

Comment: so when I use .utc the time is waaaaayyyy off. Why?

Answer (score 16):

```
var diff = moment(end).unix() - moment(start).unix();
moment.utc(moment.duration(diff).asMilliseconds()).format("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)

Comment: Explanationless or not, this is what did for me. Thanks :)

Comment: Explanation is not needed. Moment.js doc can show how this solution was achieved.

Comment: Useless. Like most other answers on this question returns partial hours in the duration not total hours. E.g. returns 12:00 for the duration moment.duration({days: 2, hours: 12})

Comment: moment.duration(diff).asMilliseconds() is excessive. You can just use diff, it's already in milliseconds.

Answer (score 15):

The best scenario for my particular use case was:

```
var duration = moment.duration("09:30"),
    formatted = moment.utc(duration.asMilliseconds()).format("HH:mm");
```

This improves upon @Wilson's answer since it does not access private internal property _data.

Answer (score 14):

You don't need .format. Use durations like this:

```
const duration = moment.duration(83, 'seconds');
console.log(duration.minutes() + ':' +duration.seconds());
// output: 1:23
```

I found this solution here: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/463

**EDIT:**

And with padding for seconds, minutes and hours:

```
const withPadding = (duration) => {
    if (duration.asDays() > 0) {
        return 'at least one day';
    } else {
        return [
            ('0' + duration.hours()).slice(-2),
            ('0' + duration.minutes()).slice(-2),
            ('0' + duration.seconds()).slice(-2),
        ].join(':')
    }
}

withPadding(moment.duration(83, 'seconds'))
// 00:01:23

withPadding(moment.duration(6048000, 'seconds'))
// at least one day
```

Comment: This won't include leading zeroes if duration.seconds() is less than 10, though...

Comment: What will happen if you have more seconds than an hour? Is it fine, that you then have more than 60 seconds?

Comment: Leading zeros works, but `duration = moment.duration(7200, 'seconds');
withPadding(duration);` will say "00:00".

Comment: @shaedrich I updated my answer again to include hours; if you need days, weeks, aso as well you can add them to the array

Comment: @ni-ko-o-kin My problem with the solution is, that I might input `1` or `604800`. Both should have proper results but no leading "00:".

Comment: `if (duration.asDays() > 0) { return 'at least one day';` - am I reading that correctly?

Answer (score 9):

I needed to do this for work as a requirement to display the hours in this format.
At first I tried this.

```
moment.utc(totalMilliseconds).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

However anything over 24 hours and the hours reset to 0.
But the minutes and seconds were accurate.
So I used only that part for the minutes and seconds.

```
var minutesSeconds = moment.utc(totalMilliseconds).format("mm:ss")
```

Now all I need is the total hours.

```
var hours = moment.duration(totalMilliseconds).asHours().toFixed()
```

And to get that format that we all want we just glue it together.

```
var formatted = hours + ":" + minutesSeconds
```

if `totalMilliseconds` is `894600000` this will return `249:30:00`.

Hope that helped. Leave any questions in the comments. ;)

Comment: Wouldn't 'toFixed()' round off the number? eg: '76.35' would become '77' and what you want is '76', and then append the hours and minutes to that. I used var hours = Math.floor(moment.duration(totalMilliseconds).asHours()). Everything else in your code is cool. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 8):

I use:

```
var duration = moment.duration("09:30");
var str = moment(duration._data).format("HH:mm");
```

And I get "09:30" in var str.

Comment: Great! This just works... how on earth did you come up with this :)

Comment: Avoid this solution, `_data` is an internal property and may change without warning.

Comment: Unfortunately it will not work always as expected: `moment(moment.duration(1200000)._data).format('hh:mm:ss')` will return 12:20 instead of 00:20

Comment: @AnnaR `h` is in range 1-12, so it's rather expectable. Use `H` instead [docs - hour tokens](https://momentjs.com/docs/#hour-minute-second-millisecond-and-offset-tokens)

Comment: This is wrong, not only that you ignore DAYS, so 1day and 1hour will be shown as 01:00. In addition you are completely ignoring Time Zones, a better solution, but **also isn't a complete** one will be  `moment.utc(...).format("HH:mm");`

Answer (score 5):

if diff is a moment

```
var diff = moment(20111031) - moment(20111010);
var formated1 = moment(diff).format("hh:mm:ss");
console.log("format 1: "+formated1);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem reliable in the face of time zones and such. Do you use this in production?

Comment: the question has no mention of time zones.

Comment: Everyone lives in a time zone. Does moment(0) always register as 12:00 AM in every time zone?

Comment: I'm simply asking if the code in your answer works or not because I am skeptical. I've written lots of code that works with dates, in many programming languages. Based on my experience, it seems that your code would only work in certain time zones – but I'm asking because perhaps there's something I don't know about how Javascript represents dates near the Unix epoch.

Comment: the second line will create a moment from start of time (1970). This won't do.

Comment: As @Harsh points out, the `moment()` constructor takes a unix timestamp, and so whatever you pass to it will be assumed to be a specific distance from 1/1/1970.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to use a different javascript library, [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) can format seconds as follows (example is for 1000 seconds):

```
var string = numeral(1000).format('00:00');
// '00:16:40'
```

Comment: definitely the way to go. as expected.

Answer (score 5):

If all hours must be displayed (more than 24) and if '0' before hours is not necessary, then formatting can be done with a short line of code:

```
Math.floor(duration.as('h')) + moment.utc(duration.as('ms')).format(':mm:ss')
```

Comment: This is the best h:mm answer, but I think the best display is simply `moment.duration(val,'seconds').humanize()`.

Comment: For my use case showing simply all hours with `mm` and `ss` was the best ways since it is compact and looks similar to a comma-separated value, and thus good for visual comparison.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [ni-ko-o-kin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44071876):

```
meassurements = ["years", "months", "weeks", "days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds"];
withPadding = (duration) => {
    var step = null;
    return meassurements.map((m) => duration[m]()).filter((n,i,a) => {
        var nonEmpty = Boolean(n);
        if (nonEmpty || step || i >= a.length - 2) {
            step = true;
        }
        return step;
    }).map((n) => ('0' + n).slice(-2)).join(':')
}

duration1 = moment.duration(1, 'seconds');
duration2 = moment.duration(7200, 'seconds');
duration3 = moment.duration(604800, 'seconds');

withPadding(duration1); // 00:01
withPadding(duration2); // 02:00:00
withPadding(duration3); // 01:07:00:00:00
```

Comment: I don't think it's very readable. What problem do you want to solve here? What is your usecase?

Comment: I updated my answer again to deal with more than one day. It works fine for my use case.

Comment: The problem is that in most cases your solution is not ideal because it contains too much leading zeros. Who wants to have "00:00:00:00:01" returned? My solution is "scalable" and adds just as much leading zeros as needed.

Comment: Works perfectly. Very simple output. If there are no days, there will be no zeros for days displayed etc.

Answer (score 5):

Short version (**one-liner**):

```
moment.duration(durationInMs).asHours()|0||"00" + ":" + moment.utc(durationInMs).format("mm:ss")
```

*Extended version:*

```
export const formatDuration = (durationInMs) => {
    const hours = Math.floor(moment.duration(durationInMs).asHours()) || "00"
    return hours + ":" + moment.utc(durationInMs).format("mm:ss")
}
```

*Example cases:*

[image: Example cases]

Answer (score 4):

I use the classic format function in these cases:

```
var diff = moment(end).unix() - moment(start).unix();

//use unix function instead of difference
moment.unix(diff).format('hh:mm:ss')
```

This is a hack because the time diff is treated as a standard moment date, an early epoch date time, but it doesn't matter to our goal and you don't need any plugin

Answer (score 3):

To format moment duration to string

```
var duration = moment.duration(86400000); //value in milliseconds
var hours = duration.hours();
var minutes = duration.minutes();
var seconds = duration.seconds();
var milliseconds = duration.milliseconds();

var date = moment().hours(hours).minutes(minutes).seconds(seconds).millisecond(milliseconds);
if (is12hr){
    return date.format("hh:mm:ss a");
}else{
    return date.format("HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you use angular add this to your filters:

```
.filter('durationFormat', function () {
    return function (value) {
        var days = Math.floor(value/86400000);
        value = value%86400000;
        var hours = Math.floor(value/3600000);
        value = value%3600000;
        var minutes = Math.floor(value/60000);
        value = value%60000;
        var seconds = Math.floor(value/1000);
        return (days? days + ' days ': '') + (hours? hours + ' hours ': '') + (minutes? minutes + ' minutes ': '') + (seconds? seconds + ' seconds ': '')
    }
})
```

usage example

```
<div> {{diff | durationFormat}} </div>
```

Comment: Very nice indeed. I was looking for a 'pretty format' like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My solution that does not involve any other library and it works with diff > 24h

```
var momentInSeconds = moment.duration(n,'seconds')
console.log(("0" + Math.floor(momentInSeconds.asHours())).slice(-2) + ':' + ("0" + momentInSeconds.minutes()).slice(-2) + ':' + ("0" + momentInSeconds.seconds()).slice(-2))
```

Answer (score 3):

**How to correctly use moment.js durations?**
|
**Use moment.duration() in code**

First you need to import `moment` and `moment-duration-format`.

```js
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-duration-format';
```

Then, use duration function. Let us apply the above example: 28800 = 8 am.

```js
moment.duration(28800, "seconds").format("h:mm a");
```

Well, you do not have above type error. Do you get a right value 8:00 am ? No…, the value you get is 8:00 a. Moment.js format is not working as it is supposed to.

The solution is to transform seconds to milliseconds and use UTC time.

```js
moment.utc(moment.duration(value, 'seconds').asMilliseconds()).format('h:mm a')
```

All right we get 8:00 am now. If you want 8 am instead of 8:00 am for integral time, we need to do RegExp

```js
const time = moment.utc(moment.duration(value, 'seconds').asMilliseconds()).format('h:mm a');
time.replace(/:00/g, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

How about native javascript?

```
var formatTime = function(integer) {
    if(integer < 10) {
        return "0" + integer; 
    } else {
        return integer;
    }
}

function getDuration(ms) {
    var s1 = Math.floor(ms/1000);
    var s2 = s1%60;
    var m1 = Math.floor(s1/60);
    var m2 = m1%60;
    var h1 = Math.floor(m1/60);
    var string = formatTime(h1) +":" + formatTime(m2) + ":" + formatTime(s2);
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format).

## Client Framework (ex: React)

```js
import moment from 'moment';
import momentDurationFormatSetup from 'moment-duration-format';
momentDurationFormatSetup(moment);

const breakLengthInMinutes = moment.duration(breakLengthInSeconds, 's').format('m');
```

## Server (node.js)

```js
const moment = require("moment-timezone");
const momentDurationFormatSetup = require("moment-duration-format");

momentDurationFormatSetup(moment);

const breakLengthInMinutes = moment.duration(breakLengthInSeconds, 's').format('m');
```

Answer (score 2):

`moment.duration(x).format()` has been deprecated.
You can use`moment.utc(4366589).format("HH:mm:ss")` to get the desired response.

```js
console.log(moment.utc(4366589).format("HH:mm:ss"))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just moment.js without any other plugins

```
moment().startOf('day').seconds(duration).format('HH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const duration = moment.duration(62, 'hours');
const n = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const days = Math.floor(duration / n);
const str = moment.utc(duration % n).format('H [h] mm [min] ss [s]');
console.log(`${days > 0 ? `${days} ${days == 1 ? 'day' : 'days'} ` : ''}${str}`);
```

Prints:

> 2 days 14 h 00 min 00 s

Answer (score 1):

There is no longer (if there ever was) any need to convert duration to utc to solve this issue. This is like converting a base10 "1" to binary and then saying that since output "1" looks like base10 we'll have no issues assuming this is a base10 value for any further operations.

Use [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) and note that with `{ trim: false }` you can prevent trimming:

```
moment.duration(1000000, "seconds").format("hh:mm:ss", { trim: false })
> "277:46:40"
moment.duration(0, "seconds").format("hh:mm:ss", { trim: false })
> "00:00:00"
```

Let's compare this with the not recommended method of  <s>using</s> abusing utc:

```
moment.utc(moment.duration(1000000, "seconds").asMilliseconds()).format('HH:mm:ss')
> "13:46:40"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
var sleep = require('sleep-promise');

(async function () {
    var t1 = new Date().getTime();
    await sleep(1000); 
    var t2 = new Date().getTime();
    var dur = moment.duration(t2-t1); 
    console.log(`${dur.hours()}h:${dur.minutes()}m:${dur.seconds()}s`);
})();
```

```
0h:0m:1s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) to format your duration:

```
numeral(your_duration.asSeconds()).format('00:00:00') // result: hh:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to get the first two characters as hours and last two as minutes. Same logic may be applied to seconds.

```js
/**
     * PT1H30M -> 0130
     * @param {ISO String} isoString
     * @return {string} absolute 4 digit number HH:mm
     */

    const parseIsoToAbsolute = (isoString) => {
    
      const durations = moment.duration(isoString).as('seconds');
      const momentInSeconds = moment.duration(durations, 'seconds');
    
      let hours = momentInSeconds.asHours().toString().length < 2
        ? momentInSeconds.asHours().toString().padStart(2, '0') : momentInSeconds.asHours().toString();
        
      if (!Number.isInteger(Number(hours))) hours = '0'+ Math.floor(hours);
    
      const minutes = momentInSeconds.minutes().toString().length < 2
        ? momentInSeconds.minutes().toString().padEnd(2, '0') : momentInSeconds.minutes().toString();
    
      const absolute = hours + minutes;
      return absolute;
    };
    
    console.log(parseIsoToAbsolute('PT1H30M'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you insert the code as a snippet, you will be able to test the method and show some output to the console.

Comment: Sure thing! Just updated with snippet for quick tests.

Answer (score 0):

as of 2017 onwards we can just use `padStart(2, "0")`
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_string_padstart.asp

just consider that this as is just grabs the seconds, so if you have 0s but up to 999ms left, this shows zero obviously.
also you obviously have to know at least what values are possible and include them. for me my app won't ever handle a day+ so I'm fine.

```
function duration_formater(duration) {
  
  // get the values from the passed duration object
  values = [duration.hours(), duration.minutes(), duration.seconds()];

  // convert numbers to strings and add leading zeros until we have two characters
  values.forEach((element, i) => {
    values[i] = element.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  });

  // return a the values as "HH:mm:ss"
  return values[0] + ":" + values[1] + ":" + values[2];
};
```

I think thats the second best solution as it's flexible to modify to your liking.

Best one is of course another / different library as this would account for all possible cases and handle everything you throw at it => bugs are impossible.

Answer (score -1):

If you use Angular >2, I made a Pipe inspired by @hai-alaluf answer.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "duration",
})

export class DurationPipe implements PipeTransform {

  public transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    // secs to ms
    value = value * 1000;
    const days = Math.floor(value / 86400000);
    value = value % 86400000;
    const hours = Math.floor(value / 3600000);
    value = value % 3600000;
    const minutes = Math.floor(value / 60000);
    value = value % 60000;
    const seconds = Math.floor(value / 1000);
    return (days ? days + " days " : "") +
      (hours ? hours + " hours " : "") +
      (minutes ? minutes + " minutes " : "") +
      (seconds ? seconds + " seconds " : "") +
      (!days && !hours && !minutes && !seconds ? 0 : "");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This works for me:

```
moment({minutes: 150}).format('HH:mm') // 01:30
```

Comment: Return "Invalid date"

Comment: 150 minutes is not 1 hour 30 minutes.