# Convert milliseconds to hours and minutes using Momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am new to Momentjs. I am trying to use it to convert milliseconds to hours and minutes. Below, x is milliseconds

```
x = 433276000
var y = moment.duration(x, 'milliseconds').asHours;
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where did you check in the moment.js documentation that you couldn't find it?

Comment: Added dot but still does not work

Comment: Now that you have added the missing dot, consider calling `asHours()` instead of evaluating it.

Comment: Looks unsupported. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262621/how-do-i-use-format-on-a-moment-js-duration

Comment: Also it doesn't look like you need to specify 'milliseconds' as an argument since it takes milliseconds. And your missing the brackets at the end: `var y = moment.duration(x).asHours();`

Answer (score 72):

I ended up doing this...

```
var x = 433276000
var tempTime = moment.duration(x);
var y = tempTime.hours() + tempTime.minutes();
```

Comment: This is clearly the correct answer, since `tempTime.minutes()` gives the remaining minutes after the hours are computed.

Comment: This doesn't work for durations of 24 hours or more.

Comment: It works when I change the last line to
`var y = tempTime.hours() + ":" + tempTime.minutes();`

Comment: Use `moment.duration(x).asMinutes()` This also works for 24 hours+

Comment: Just ran into duration(x).humanize() which translates the duration to the right time frame. might help someone...
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/

Answer (score 33):

Try this:

```
var x = 433276000
var d = moment.duration(x, 'milliseconds');
var hours = Math.floor(d.asHours());
var mins = Math.floor(d.asMinutes()) - hours * 60;
console.log("hours:" + hours + " mins:" + mins);
```

Comment: Why do you need `var mins = Math.floor(d.asMinutes()) - hours * 60;` if you could simply use `var mins = d.minutes()` ?

Comment: @AlexG what about seconds

Comment: @Kalashir, that wasn't in the question.

Answer (score 33):

You can create a Moment.js date from milliseconds using [moment.utc()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

```js
var milliseconds = 1000;
moment.utc(milliseconds).format('HH:mm');
```

Comment: This is perfect. If you want > 24h, just add days or display hours only. https://codepen.io/h3ll/pen/VQdGMy

Comment: This way is the best

Answer (score 21):

Using the [moment-duration-format plugin](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format):

```
moment.duration(ms).format("h:mm")
```

Answer (score 10):

There is an easier way to achieve what you want.

This

```
moment('2000-01-01 00:00:00').add(moment.duration(1000)).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

Will output this

```
00:00:01
```

Not the fanciest, I know, but it is 100% pure moment js.

***edit***: Doesn't work for periods longer than 24h

Answer (score 2):

This seems unsupported [per this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13274554/1339987). Following [this github issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/463), there's a [moment-to-countdown plugin](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/463) that you may be able to use.

But it seems you may want [Countdown.js](http://countdownjs.org/) for this in the first place.

```
countdown(0, 433276000, countdown.HOURS | countdown.MINUTES).toString();
```

Note this does not take into account leap seconds, or leap anything for that matter, as it fixes to the Unix epoch (so it's not a pure time interval).

Answer (score 2):

There really is no need to use Moment for this operation.

It can be written in a single line:

`var hours = Math.round((450616708 / 1000 / 60 / 60) * 100) / 100;`

or as function:

```js
function millisecondsToHours(ms){
  return Math.round((ms / 1000 / 60 / 60) * 100) / 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Moment.js duration you can just use Math.trunc for hours if you are expecting it to be over 24hrs. hh:mm:ss format.

```
var seconds = moment.duration(value).seconds();
var minutes = moment.duration(value).minutes();
var hours = Math.trunc(moment.duration(value).asHours());
```

see it here: https://codepen.io/brickgale/pen/mWqKJv?editors=1011

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that formats it for you into a string.

```
function ms_to_str(val) {

    let tempTime = moment.duration(val),
        timeObj = {
            years: tempTime.years(),
            months: tempTime.months(),
            days: tempTime.days(),
            hrs: tempTime.hours(),
            mins: tempTime.minutes(),
            secs: tempTime.seconds(),
            ms: tempTime.milliseconds()
        },

        timeArr = [];

    for (let k in timeObj) {
        if (Number(timeObj[k]) > 0) {
            timeArr.push(`${timeObj[k]} ${k}`)
        }
    }

    return timeArr.join(', ');
}
```

Then simply call `ms_to_str(2443253)` which returns `40 mins, 43 secs, 253 ms`.

If you do not need to show milliseconds, simply comment off the `ms: tempTime.milliseconds().toString().padStart(3, '0')` line.

Answer (score 1):

Momentjs itself doesn't support duration, in order to do so, we need a plugin [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format)

To use this plugin follow these steps (for React-js)

```
import moment from 'moment';
import momentDurationFormatSetup from "moment-duration-format";

var time = moment.duration(value,unit).format('hh:mm:ss',{trim:false})
```

Note: I have used {trim: false} as extra parameter so that it doesn't trim out extra 0's in the beginning. You can omit it if you want "11:30" instead of "00:11:30".

Comment: Momentjs [does support durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/hours/).

Comment: need to add plugin still https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/

Answer (score 0):

```
function durationAsString(ms, maxPrecission = 3) {
    const duration = moment.duration(ms)

    const items = []
    items.push({ timeUnit: 'd', value: Math.floor(duration.asDays()) })
    items.push({ timeUnit: 'h', value: duration.hours() })
    items.push({ timeUnit: 'm', value: duration.minutes() })
    items.push({ timeUnit: 's', value: duration.seconds() })

    const formattedItems = items.reduce((accumulator, { value, timeUnit }) => {
        if (accumulator.length >= maxPrecission || (accumulator.length === 0 && value === 0)) {
            return accumulator
        }

        accumulator.push(`${value}${timeUnit}`)
        return accumulator
    }, [])

    return formattedItems.length !== 0 ? formattedItems.join(' ') : '-'
}
```

Lets you set max-precision and will not show insignificant values.
Examples:

`durationAsString(0)` will return `-`

`durationAsString(10000)` will return `10s`

`durationAsString(100000)` will return `1m 40s`

`durationAsString(10000000)` will return `2h 46m 40s`

`durationAsString(100000000)` will return `1d 3h 46m`

`durationAsString(100000000, 4)` will return `1d 3h 46m 40s`

Answer (score -3):

moment('2000-01-01 00:00:00').millisecond(XXXXXX).format("HH:mm:ss")