# Convert thousands of seconds to h:mm:ss in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've been going through the docs and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I need to convert `7200` to `2:00:00`. Seems easy? Some attempts:

```
var duration = 7200;
var display = moment().seconds(duration).format("h:mm:ss");
```

and...

```
var duration = 7200;
var display = moment.duration(duration, "seconds"); //can't chain on a format method?
```

The format comes back correct but the numbers are all wrong. If I use a duration of `Math.round(7025.526)` or `7025.526` I get `9:19:06` back.

How can I convert seconds to `h:mm:ss` successfully?

Comment: You might some tips from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938300/convert-milliseconds-to-hours-and-minutes-using-momentjs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use `moment().seconds(duration)` it will take the current date and time, and then set the seconds component to the value (spilling over into minutes and hours). If you try it at different times you will see that the result changes.

A duration object can't be formatted as a date, because it's simply not a date. It's a length of time without any defined starting or ending point.

To convert the seconds first create an empty moment object, which will be the current date and the time 0:00:00. Then you can set the seconds, which will spill over into minutes and hours.

You would want to use `H` rather than `h` to format the hours. That avoids getting times less than an hour as `12:nn:nn` instead of `0:nn:nn`:

```
var duration = 7200;
var display = moment({}).seconds(duration).format("H:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Yes, except this won't work for durations of 24 hours or more.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't spot the part in the docs where they tell you send an empty object...

Comment: @discardthis: ¨There is no example of an empty object, but *"Omitted units default to 0 or the current date, month, and year."* and there is no requirement of any of the properties to be present.

Answer (score 3):

```
let duration = seconds;
let hours = duration/3600;
duration = duration % (3600);

let min = parseInt(duration/60);
duration = duration % (60);

let sec = parseInt(duration);

if (sec < 10) {
  sec = `0${sec}`;
}
if (min < 10) {
  min = `0${min}`;
}
if (parseInt(hours, 10) > 0) {
  return (`${parseInt(hours, 10)} : ${min} : ${sec}`)
}
return (`${min} : ${sec}`)
```

You can do it manually by calculating hours minutes and seconds

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to zero-pad the minutes and seconds fields, and truncate decimals from the hours and minutes fields.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [moment-duration-format plugin](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format):

```
var s = moment.duration(ms).format("h:mm:ss");
```

Or, just using moment:

```
var d = moment.duration(ms);
var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");
```