# Converting Milliseconds to Minutes and Seconds in momentjs

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

1.from: 2380 //time in milliseconds to minutes and seconds
  example:
  2380 is 0.2 sec convert to 00:02 (min:sec)

```
var fromDuration = moment.duration(from, 'milliseconds');
var fromMinutes = Math.ceil(fromDuration.asMinutes());
var fromSeconds = Math.ceil(fromDuration.asSeconds());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert milliseconds to hours and minutes using Momentjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938300/convert-milliseconds-to-hours-and-minutes-using-momentjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is:

```
const millisecondsToMinutesSeconds = (ms) => {
  let duration = moment.duration(ms, 'milliseconds');
  let fromMinutes = Math.floor(duration.asMinutes());
  let fromSeconds = Math.floor(duration.asSeconds() - fromMinutes * 60);

  return Math.floor(duration.asSeconds()) >= 60 ? (fromMinutes<= 9 ? '0'+fromMinutes : fromMinutes) +':'+ (fromSeconds<= 9 ? '0'+fromSeconds : fromSeconds)
: '00:'+(fromSeconds<= 9 ? '0'+fromSeconds : fromSeconds);

};
```