# Formatting milliseconds into hh:mm:ss - extraneous hours added

Tags: date, time, format, momentjs

I'm using momentJS to find the difference between two times and format to hh:mm:ss. `Ver: "moment": "~2.10.6"`

The problem I'm having is an extraneous 7 hours being added to a time whose difference is only 1 minute, 1 second.

```
var diff_ms = moment('2016-07-29 10:35:18').diff('2016-07-29 10:34:17');
```

> 61000

```
var diff = moment(diff_ms).format('hh mm ss')
```

> "07 01 01"

[Convert milliseconds to hours and minutes using Momentjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938300/convert-milliseconds-to-hours-and-minutes-using-momentjs) says to specify the time unit as milliseconds, `moment.duration(x, 'milliseconds');`, but since it's returning the correct minutes and seconds (`01 01`), it seems it's correctly defaulting to milliseconds.

I can do this the "un-momentJS" way:

```
var a = moment.duration(61000, 'milliseconds');
```

> a: n {_milliseconds: 61000, _days: 0, _months: 0, _data: Object,
>   _locale: l}

```
var b = a.hours() + ':' + a.minutes() + ':' + a.seconds();
```

> b: 0:1:1

But don't have an easy way of formatting this output to hh:mm:ss using string concatenation like this.

Comment: Check if a.seconds/minutes/hours.length  is < 2, if yes you could add a 0 in front