# MomentJS - Convvert Milliseconds to format(1 Hour and 7 minutes)

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I have a transformation to make. I am using `MomentJS`, and I am trying to take `milliseconds` and convert them to the format `1 Hour and 7 Mins` for **example**.

I can make it work like this 1,1 Hours with the following code, where `interval` is the time in ms:

```
moment
      .duration(interval)
      .asSeconds()
      .toFixed(0)
```

How can I make this work. Take `ms` and transform them into human-readable formats.

> By the way, I tried the `humanize` method, but didn't cover them. Just FYI..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938300/convert-milliseconds-to-hours-and-minutes-using-momentjs

Comment: Show that. Not what I am asking. Thanks though..

Answer (score 0):

Moment doesn't seem to support what you are asking out of the box, but you can get the values of various time units (years, months, days ...) of your duration using [the get function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/get/).

Based on this information, I put together a couple of functions that generate the output you are looking for:

```js
let duration = moment.duration(122101000);

let units = [
  {unit: "years", singular: "Year", plural: "Years"},
  {unit: "months", singular: "Month", plural: "Months"},
  {unit: "days", singular: "Day", plural: "Days"},
  {unit: "hours", singular: "Hour", plural: "Hours"},
  {unit: "minutes", singular: "Minute", plural: "Minutes"},
  {unit: "seconds", singular: "Second", plural: "Seconds"}
];

console.log(output(deconstruct(duration, units)));

function output(entries)
{
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    let entry = entries[i];
    if (i > 0) {
      result += ', ' + (i == entries.length - 1 ? "and " : "");
    }
    result += entry.unitValue + " " + (entry.unitValue == 1 ? entry.unit.singular : entry.unit.plural);
  }
  return result;
}

function deconstruct(duration, units)
{
  let values = [], unitValue;
  for (let unit of units) {
    if (unitValue = duration.get(unit.unit)) {
      values.push({"unitValue": unitValue, "unit": unit})
    }
  }
  return values;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```