# using moment.js to display duration in format 00:XX when duration is less than an hour

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to format a countdown timer using moment duration format
but as soon as time hits below 60 minutes , the hours disappear
e.g. 60 minutes display as "01:00"
which is correct
59 minutes display as  "59" 
which is not correct, it should display as "00:59"

where 3500000 milliseconds is equal to 58 minutes

I have the following code:

```
moment.duration(3500000).format("hh:mm", { forceLength: true })
```

which displays result : 58, rather than 00:58

what am I doing wrong here ?

I have also attempted the variation to no avail

```
moment.duration(3500000).format("HH:mm", { forceLength: true })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use format() on a moment.js duration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262621/how-do-i-use-format-on-a-moment-js-duration)

Comment: I saw that one earlier, it's an older thread at the time when duration didn't support formatting - now it does, only it's not formatting it right

Comment: For me it's an exception saying that `duration` don't have method `format`

Comment: @RC. But it gives `UTC` which in this case gives `12:58`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
moment(moment.duration(3500000)._data).format("HH:mm");
```

Comment: this worked, your a champion - thanks! - could you tell me where ._data comes from ? I don't see it in the documentation anywhere

Comment: @Danish `duration` object have `_data` which contains the time `object` we need for formatting.

Comment: in my opinion the forceLength option with format should have produced the desired result, rendering other non available values to 0 - perhaps missing implementation internally ?

Comment: May be we may have proper answer. Until then consider this as a workaround. :)

Comment: `moment.utc(3500000).format("HH:mm");` gives the same result without relying on any internals.  Either way, the only problem is that it's only going to work up to 24 hours.

Answer (score 11):

I can explain what's happening (I created the `moment-duration-format` plugin).

The `forceLength` option only affects the first token **that has a value**, meaning the first token with a value greater than `0`. In your case, the `hh` token doesn't have a value.
https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#force-length

Switching from `hh` to `HH` means something for formatting moment objects (dates), but not for formatting moment duration objects (lengths of time) with my plugin (unless you've customized the duration formatting tokens, which is possible using my plugin).

Using `moment(moment.duration(3500000)._data).format("HH:mm");` as suggested is a nice creative workaround.

If you want to grab the version of moment-duration-format that's on the repository's `dev` branch, there is an option that can help (see https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format/issues/22)...

In that version you can use the `*` character to denote the minimum token to show while trimming, even with it has no value:

```
moment.duration(3510000).format("*hh:mm");
--> "00:59"
moment.duration(3509999).format("*hh:mm");
--> "00:58"
```

Note that the default behaviour in the `dev` branch version changed from `truncate` to `round` so you'll drop from `00:59` to `00:58` as you pass from `58 minutes 30 seconds` to `58 minutes 29 seconds`. In that version you could turn on the `trunc` option for this output:

```
moment.duration(3539999).format("*hh:mm", { trunc: true });
--> "00:58"
moment.duration(3540000).format("*hh:mm", { trunc: true });
--> "00:59"
```

Not sure if that's what you would want for your countdown solution... maybe a feature of setting `floor` (`trunc`), `ceiling`, or `round` on the remainder would be best?

If you wanted a ceiling behaviour, you could use the `dev` branch version along with `trunc` and add `60000` to your timer value:

```
moment.duration(3540000 + 60000).format("*hh:mm", { trunc: true });
--> "01:00"
moment.duration(3539999 + 60000).format("*hh:mm", { trunc: true });
--> "00:59"
moment.duration(3500000 + 60000).format("*hh:mm", { trunc: true });
--> "00:59"
moment.duration(3480000 + 60000).format("*hh:mm", { trunc: true });
--> "00:59"
moment.duration(3479999 + 60000).format("*hh:mm", { trunc: true });
--> "00:58"
```

Comment: Thanks john, its a financial trading app so times have to be accurate , the solution provided here in answer only works when the duration is less than 60 minutes , on larger durations it gives out weird times - hopefully as you mentioned , we will have this feature incorporated in the future  releases

Answer (score 4):

Try 'trim' parameter.

```
moment.duration(3500000).format("hh:mm", { trim: false })
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my use-case without any additional dependencies!

Answer (score 1):

My variant

```
moment.utc(3400000).format("HH:mm")
```

gives : "00:56"

Hope will be usefull.

Comment: hmm.. didn't try it - might work
actual implementation that I have is like moment.duration(moment(this.date).diff(moment())).format("hh:mm")

so far I've done a work around where I do the provided solution by Jyothi Babu Araja, if I detect the duration to be less than 60 minutes, else I apply just normal formatting