# Moment.js: How to display a time value only

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

This should be easy... but I've had no luck scouring the docs!

How do I get Moment.js to return: `15 minutes`

In order to get `15 minutes ago` I can write:

`moment().subtract(15, 'minutes').fromNow()`

Which command should I use to get just `15 minutes`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use format() on a moment.js duration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262621/how-do-i-use-format-on-a-moment-js-duration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to explicitly remove the "ago" or similar phrasing, simply pass `true` to your `fromNow()` function as [detailed in the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/):

```
moment().subtract(15, 'minutes').fromNow(true);
```

**Example**

```js
console.log(moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow());     // "10 years ago"
console.log(moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow(true)); // "10 years"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.10.6/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! If you fancy another challenge... `Moment().subtract(1, 'hour').fromNow(true)` returns `an hour`. Can it be made to say `1 hour`?

Comment: If you want to adjust these, you can make changes to [the relative time locale settings](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/), which allow you to define which phrases you want to use, etc. So you could replace "an hour" with "1 hour".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/).

**Duration from the difference between two dates:**

```
var now = moment();
var then = moment().subtract(15, 'minutes');
moment.duration(now.diff(then)).humanize();
```

> 15 minutes

**Duration without using dates:**

```
moment.duration(15, 'minutes').humanize();
```

> 15 minutes