# Property 'format' does not exist on type 'Duration'

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, momentjs

I'm trying to use "moment-duration-formation" in TypeScript but, even though it works, webpack keeps on complaining that it can't find the "format" method on the line:

```
return moment.duration(value, "minutes").format("...");
```

Here is the package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/moment-duration-format": "^1.3.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-duration-format": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

And the tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types" ]
  }
}
```

In the (angular2) component:

```
import * as moment from "moment";
import * as momentDurationFormat from "moment-duration-format";

...

let result: string = moment.duration(this.selectedHangarDistance * 10, "minutes").format("...")
```

I also tried with

```
import "moment-duration-format";
```

But it does not change anything:

> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   ./src/app/components/building/shop/shop.component.ts:190:81 TS2339:
>   Property 'format' does not exist on type 'Duration'.

Comment: I'm not seeing the types for moment. Did you `npm install --save-dev @types/moment`?

Comment: I just installed them but they're totally empty (no .d.ts file) and the readme file states "Moment provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/moment installed!".

Comment: Better solutions is there here, this worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262621/how-do-i-use-format-on-a-moment-js-duration

Answer (score 5):

A solution that worked for me:

```
import * as moment from "moment";
import momentDurationFormatSetup from "moment-duration-format";
momentDurationFormatSetup(moment);
```

The `* as moment` was significant as `import moment from "moment"` was causing type issues when being passed `momentDurationFormatSetup`.

Answer (score 1):

Run `yarn add --dev @types/moment-duration-format` or `npm install --save-dev @types/moment-duration-format`