# Convert moment.Duration into string

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I have a `moment.Duration` object which I need to convert to string format `HH:mm:ss` (without any timezone conversion). I know we can do like

```
foobar.hours + ":" + foobar.minutes + ":" + foobar.seconds
```

But honestly I was hoping to have a better solution that just string manipulations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use format() on a moment.js duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262621/how-do-i-use-format-on-a-moment-js-duration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var now = moment()
var then = moment().subtract(3, 'hours').subtract(20, 'minutes')

const duration = now.subtract(then)

duration.format("HH:mm:ss")

>> 03:20:00
```

Answer (score 0):

moment().format('HH:mm:ss');
if u have already moment object use like this

object.format('HH:mm:ss');

Comment: It gives error - Property 'format' does not exist on type 'Duration'

Comment: moment.utc(duration.as('milliseconds')).format('HH:mm:ss')
or
moment.duration.as('milliseconds').format('HH:mm:ss')

this happened because, your object has duration type

Comment: My code
    row.time.format("HH:MM:ss")

Here row is loop variable and time is duration variable.

Comment: row.time.duration.as('milliseconds').format('HH:mm:ss')

this will work