# How to format Time Duration using moment.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have written code to find out the diff of two Dates.  I have successfully done this. but the output has given so long format like that: `DIFF-DATE 0.019110277777777778:1.1466166666666666:68.797`. But I want to format like that **01:20:59** means `HH:mm:ss` so, please suggest somethings

Here's my Code:

```
/*---StrtDate---*/

   componentDidMount(){
        let{StrtDate}=this.state

        this.setState({ StrtDate: moment(new Date()) })
    }

/*---EndDate--*/

  bookingEndTime(){
        let { StrtDate, EndDate}=this.state;
        var end = moment(new Date());
        this.setState({ EndDate: end}, ()=> {
        var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(StrtDate));
        var Hours = duration.asHours();
        var Minutes = duration.asMinutes();
        var Seconds = duration.asSeconds();
        console.log('DIFF-DATE', (Hours +":" + Minutes+ ":" + Seconds))
        })


    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the actual `moment` formatting? https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262621/how-do-i-use-format-on-a-moment-js-duration

Comment: Suggested answer in the linked duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25386127/4131048

Answer (score 0):

Visit momentjs formatting: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Below is a sample

```
var moment = require("moment"); 
var input = "2020-02-27T01:23:44-05:30";
var converted = moment(input).format("HH:mm:ss"); 
console.log(converted);
```