# Convert Time difference into HH:MM:SS using moment/JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a `startTime` and `endTime` based on which I need to create a countdown which will display in `HH:MM:SS` format at all times.

For example:

```js
var endTime = 1601454312537 // Wed Sep 30 2020 13:55:12 
var startTime = 1600417512537 // Fri Sep 18 2020 13:55:12 
var diff = endTime - startTime
var duration = moment.duration(diffTime * 1000, 'milliseconds')
```

The difference is then passed to setInterval where,

```js
setInterval(() => {
    duration = moment.duration(duration - interval, 'milliseconds');
    h = duration.hours(),
    m = duration.minutes(),
    s = duration.seconds() 
}, 1000);
```

This gives me correct time but when it exceeds 24 hrs, moment passes it in a day.
Is there any way I can keep it all the diff in HH:MM:SS format?
Is there any moment function to restrict it to hours, min, sec?

Comment: Does that cause any issue in code if it passes it as day?

Comment: Something like `h= duration.days() * 24 + duration.hours()` …? (Whether that might get you in trouble with DST at some point, I leave for you to figure out.)

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava I need to display it in hours .Even if its 24+ ,doesn't matter.

Comment: Look at this https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/463; I would rather use countdown.js for this http://countdownjs.org/

Comment: Or you can also refer this https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13274554/5605822

Comment: @04FS Would cause issues..Will try it out

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Don't actually want to add separate dependancy.Moment doesn't internally have anything like this?

Comment: @AbhijeetKhairnar No did you see the issue I sent you there is the discussion for this feature

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Checking that.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262621/how-do-i-use-format-on-a-moment-js-duration

Comment: @TasosBu Solution posted in your link works.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution which worked for me -
You can further split the minutesSeconds string.

```
var minutesSeconds = moment.utc(totalMilliseconds).format("mm:ss")
var hours = Math.floor(moment.duration(totalMilliseconds).asHours())
console.log("HH:MM:SS",hours + ':' + minutesSeconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one function that I use that does not require `momentjs`, there is no direct way to do this in `momentjs` either:

```
// Duration in seconds
const durationString = duration =>
  `${
    Math.floor(duration / 60) > 9 ? Math.floor(duration / 60) : `0${Math.floor(duration / 60)}`
  } m ${duration % 60 > 9 ? Math.round(duration % 60) : `0${Math.round(duration % 60)}`}s`
```