# how to convert minutes to HH:mm with moment plugin

Tags: javascript, momentjs, time-format

I have 2 timestamps and i already calculated the time difference in minutes with moment plugin. Now i want to convert the minutes to HH:mm.

```
var x = moment('10:00', 'HH:mm');
var y = moment('11:30', 'HH:mm');
var diff = y.diff(x, 'minutes'); // 90 
var convert = moment.duration(diff, "minutes").format('HH:mm');
alert(convert); // should give me 01:30 but does not work
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error coming?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: moment is not a function`

Comment: this looks like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262621/how-to-use-format-on-a-moment-js-duration . I get a different error, curiously (it complains that format is not a function on a duration object) so there may be something environment-specific too, but you're not supposed to be able to format durations (with moment alone), and you never will be. Cf. https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1048 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not specified what is the error, I'm assuming you are leaving the dependencies required for duration method.

The moment-duration-format depends on [moment](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#module), so you should require it before using it.

```
npm install moment moment-duration-format
```

Then either you can import the dependencies or require them.

```
import moment from "moment";
import "moment-duration-format";
```

```js
 var moment = require("moment");
  require("moment-duration-format");
  var x = moment("10:00", "HH:mm");
  var y = moment("11:30", "HH:mm");
  var diff = y.diff(x, "minutes"); // 90
  var convert = moment.duration(diff, "minutes").format("HH:mm");
  alert(convert);
```

**Note:** *require* is a Node.JS function and doesn't work in client side scripting without certain requirements. [More info](https://requirejs.org/)

Hope it helps
Thanks

Comment: yes indeed. I got the error: `require is not defined`

Comment: I have updated my answer with a note, can you tell where are you using this code, in a NodeJS environment or in browser

Comment: In a browser and i got it working now: In the head below moment plugin:`<script src="js/moment-duration-format.js"></script>`: and then the alert works fine WITHOUT these lines: `var moment = require("moment");
var momentDurationFormatSetup = require("moment-duration-format");`