# Elapsed ms to day?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm converting elapsed ms to HH:mm:ss, but if the elapsed ms are higher of a day, I lost [that](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldoxtchq/) info:

```
const elapsedSeconds = 218509
const elapsed = moment.utc(elapsedSeconds * 1000).format('HH:mm:ss');
alert(elapsed); // print 12:41:49
```

How can I also display days from ms, near the HH:mm:ss?
In this case there are 60hours, so it should print 2(days):12:41:49. Or 60:41:49 at least.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `.format('d HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: try `const elapsed = moment.utc(elapsedSeconds * 1000).format('DD:HH:mm:ss');` will give result `00:12:41:49`

Comment: Neither of two works. In this case there are 60hours, so it should print 2(days):12:41:49. Or 60:41:49 at least...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use format() on a moment.js duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262621/how-to-use-format-on-a-moment-js-duration)

Comment: You can easily do this with sum, diff, mod and division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on your required ouput you can use moment library to convert date time to specified format.

For that your code looks like :

```
const elapsedMilliseconds = 218509000;
const duration = moment.duration(elapsedMilliseconds);
const elapsed = duration.days() + "(days):" + duration.hours() + ":" + duration.minutes() + ":" + duration.seconds();
alert(elapsed);
```

**Result :**

```
2(days):12:41:49
```

If you want to do by javascript to get total HH:mm:ss then :

```
function padTo2Digits(num) {
  return num.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

function convertMsToHM(milliseconds) {
  let seconds = Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000);
  let minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  let hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);

  seconds = seconds % 60;
  minutes = seconds >= 30 ? minutes + 1 : minutes;
  minutes = minutes % 60;

  return `${padTo2Digits(hours)}:${padTo2Digits(minutes)}:${padTo2Digits(seconds)}`;
}

console.log(convertMsToHM(218509000));
```

**Result :**

```
"60:42:49"
```

Comment: How can I display 2 digit every :? It prints weird stuff, such as 0:0:10:3 in case of 10 minutes and 3 seconds...

Comment: You can simply use custom `padTo2Digits` function to convert double digit value.