# How do we make momentJS display 60 minutes in mm:ss format?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment js to format milliseconds into a `mm:ss` format with the following code

```
moment(myVariable).format('mm:ss');
```

This works perfectly fine, however a requirement for the app I'm building needs to show 60 minutes as `60:00` rather than using hours like `01:00:00`.  I came across another post that suggested doing

```
moment.duration(myVariable, 'seconds').asMinutes();
```

however it formats `3,600,000 milliseconds` into minutes as `60000` instead of `60:00`.  Is there a way to make it display as `60:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate string manually:

```
var d = moment.duration(3600000); // in ms
// slice used for add leading zero
var str = `${d.hours() * 60 + d.minutes()}:${('0' + d.seconds()).slice(-2)}`;
```

Comment: I think it's not possible to do this via moment.js.
You can view this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262621/how-to-use-format-on-a-moment-js-duration

Comment: One more thing.  When the minutes gets down to less than 10 the minutes are displayed in single digits such as `9:57` and I need it to display as `09:57`.  How could I make it do that?

Comment: @Optiq you can use example for seconds from my answer or visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can consider using `.diff` method:

```js
const m = moment(myVariable);
`${m.diff(0, 'minutes').padStart(2, '0')}:${m.format('ss')}`;
```